# How to route several html files in the same directory injecting as a variable

Tags: python, flask

Inside my templates folder there's another folder called templates/destinations. Inside 'destinations' folder, I have got 8 html files. When I tried to pass each destination as a variable like in the following code, I get a 404 error. What's wrong with my code?

demo.py as follows
from flask import Flask, render_template

```
@app.route('/destinations/{city}', methods = ['GET'])
def destinations(city):
    destn = 'destinations/'+city+'.html'
    return render_template(destn)
```

html navigation code as follows

```
<ul class="nav-dropdown">
      <li><a href="destinations/london">London</a></li>
      <li><a href="destinations/ny">New York</a></li>
      <li><a href="destinations/paris">Paris</a></li>
```

Comment: What is the value of "city" in your method (use print or pdb to figure out)? Also, what is the end value of destn right before the return? Your code looks fine to me.

Comment: @Ludo21South if you look at the code they have `{city}` instead of `<city>` in the route.

Comment: Well spotted @CodeLikeBeaker .  I missed that one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Replace the curly bracket,
Instead of:

```
@app.route('/destinations/{city}', methods = ['GET'])
```

Change to

```
@app.route('/destinations/<city>', methods = ['GET'])
```

Doc: https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/1.1.x/quickstart/#variable-rules